# Apple Mac OS X Notarisation of multiple bundles sharing common frameworks

Tags: macos, frameworks, bundle, notarize

I'm struggling to find a solution to notarise my app with Apple.
I've passed the complete process and I'm also able to stamp my DMG that actually contains 3 bundles that shares a vast amount of common frameworks.

While launching the application once downloading it on a new machine, Gatekeeper keep saying that the application is from an unknown developer. After an extensive research and through the system.log , the problem seems to be that any framework or .dylib MUST BE inside the bundle into the Framework directory, while in my scenario, I've a top level folder with the frameworks , and all 3 bundles uses @loader_path to link to the frameworks that are 1 level external to their root.

So, if I want to distribute the application into a single DMG and avoid having a 200+ MB DMG by duplicating the frameworks into each bundle (and this will be also a mess because the apps shares some common configuration files and the entire directory structure will be somewhat incompressible to the end user), is there a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay got a ticket back from Apple, for the ones with my problem, the choices are basically 2:

1) Duplicate the frameworks, this includes only frameworks directly linked by the executable. Plugins or other stuff that's loaded at runtime can stay on another location

2) Install the shared frameworks inside /Library/Frameworks.

No other options, thanks Apple I have to work several hours to rework the entire thing!

Comment: I deleted my answer not to lead others astray. ;) Unfortunately, that's what I was afraid of.

Comment: seams the best way to go now is creating a flag .pkg and no longer use DMG unless you want to pack multiple .pkg installers into one DMG , in that case you need to sign either the .dmg and the individual .pkg